# Reactjs replicates form input content as I typed

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs replicates form input content as I typed

This code displays three input forms. 
**My issue is that when I type in the first input form, am seeing my typed content appearing on the 2nd and 3rd input form also.**

Please how do I keep typed content in each of the input form seperately.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class AutoComment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
comment: '',
      data: [],
      shown: true,


    };
 this.handleChangeComment = this.handleChangeComment.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", title: "my first title" },
        { id: "2", title: "my second title" },
        { id: "3", title: "my third title" }
      ]
    });
  }





 handleChangeComment(event) {
const { name, value } = event.target;
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

 handleComment(id, comments) {
   alert('am id:' +id);
alert('am id:' +comments);
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((post, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
{post.id}----{post.title}

<textarea rows="2" cols="20" className="form-control img-rounded"  name="comment"  value={this.state.comment} onChange={this.handleChangeComment} placeholder="Write a Comment..">Write Comment</textarea>

<input type="button" value="comment"   onClick={() => this.handleComment(post.id, this.state.comment)}  />
                <br />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a controlled input, however, all three elements are referencing the same state, hence why when you change one, you're changing all of them.

**Edit:**

Here is a code example: https://jsfiddle.net/yegac34n/

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" className="form-control img-rounded"  name={`comment-${i}`}  value={this.state[`comment-${i}`]} onChange={this.handleChangeComment} placeholder="Write a Comment..">Write Comment</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response so far Sir Tombraider. please can you illustrate more with coding example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are having same state value for all of text areas. you can have

```
<textarea name={`comment${i}`}  value={this.state[`comment${i}`]}
```

or you can have state variable comment as an array, and then update that index of array, which can be

```
<textarea   value={this.state.comment[i]} onChange={(e) => handleChangeComment(e, i)}
```